# What is the order of evaluation of the assignment and equality operators in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, operators

Since both the assignment operator and equality operator are the same character (`=`), which operation takes precedence in an expression where both uses are intended?

As an example, what does this line of code do?

```vb
MyThing = Session("WHATEVER") = "A"
```

I'm looking through some legacy code and there are a lot of expressions that are just like this. In the languages I am familiar with, this would be a double assignment. However, everywhere these expressions are used, the variable on the left hand side of the first operator are to be assumed to be a boolean.

```vb
If (MyThing) 
    doStuff() 
EndIf
```

So which is it? Is `MyThing` equal to "A" or is it a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statements are evaluated left-to-right. In your example the statement starts with a variable followed by `=`, so you have an L-value followed by an operator and some expression. In this situation the `=` is interpreted as an assignment operator. The remainder of the statement becomes an R-value expression, so all other `=` operators are interpreted as comparison operators. Ergo is the value of `MyThing` boolean.

VBScript does not support multiple assignments like Python.

Answer (score 2):

`MyThing` is a boolean, specifically if `Session("WHATEVER")` contains "A", then `MyThing` is true, otherwise it's false. In other words, the first equal sign is the assignment operator, while the second is the equality operator.

Personally, I'd add parentheses to make the intended action clearer, i.e.

```
MyThing = (Session("WHATEVER") = "A")
```

but in most cases, it'll work without parentheses.

<sub>There's similar overloading of `AND`: it's both the boolean operator and the bitwise arithmetic operator. Like the equal sign, most of the time the interpreter will get it correct, but parentheses are still a good idea, because *sometimes* -- not always -- it'll do unexpected things if you try</sub>

```
If MySettings AND ThisFlag > 0 Then
```

<sub>-- as in, sometimes the above will be interpreted as `(MySettings = True) AND (ThisFlag > 0)` instead of the intended `(MySettings AND ThisFlag) > 0`.</sub>